# Convert a string into hash value in matlab

Tags: hash, matlab-figure

How can I convert a message into a hash value using SHA/MD5 hashing in MATLAB? is there any builtin function or any fixed code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no functions in matlab to calculate hashes. However, you can call Java (any OS) or .Net (Windows only) functions directly from matlab and either of these implement what you want.

Note that you haven't specified the encoding of the string. The hash is different if you consider the string in ASCII, UTF8, UTF16, etc.

Also note that matlab does not have 160-bit or 256-bit integer, so the hash can't obviously be a single integer.

Anyway, using .Net:

**SHA256**

```
string = 'some string'; 
sha256hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed;
sha256 = uint8(sha256hasher.ComputeHash(uint8(string)));
dec2hex(sha256)
```

**SHA1**

```
sha1hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1Managed;
sha1= uint8(sha1hasher.ComputeHash(uint8(string)));
dec2hex(sha1)
```

Java based solution can be found in the following link
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/45323-how-to-calculate-hash-sum-of-a-string-using-java

Comment: very hacky, very nice :D

Comment: if I'm not wrong, is there two different code? 1st one is for SHA256 HASHING and 2nd one is for SHA1 hashing? @casillas

Comment: Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB's .NET classes appear to be a more recent creation than the JAVA hashing.
However, these classes don't have much/any public documentation available.  After playing with it a bit, I found a way to specify one of several hash algorithms, as desired.

The "System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm" constructor accepts a hash algorithm name (string).   Based on the string name you pass in, it returns different hasher classes (.SHA256Managed is only one type).   See the example below for a complete string input ==> hash string output generation.

```
% Available options are 'SHA1', 'SHA256', 'SHA384', 'SHA512', 'MD5'
algorithm = 'SHA1';   

% SHA1 category
hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create('SHA1');  % DEFAULT

% SHA2 category
hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create('SHA256');  
hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create('SHA384');  
hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create('SHA512');

% SHA3 category:   Does not appear to be supported

% MD5 category
hasher = System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.Create('MD5');

% GENERATING THE HASH:
str = 'Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country';
hash_byte = hasher.ComputeHash( uint8(str) );  % System.Byte class
hash_uint8 = uint8( hash_byte );               % Array of uint8
hash_hex = dec2hex(hash_uint8);                % Array of 2-char hex codes

% Generate the hex codes as 1 long series of characters
hashStr = str([]);
nBytes = length(hash_hex);
for k=1:nBytes
    hashStr(end+1:end+2) = hash_hex(k,:);
end
fprintf(1, '\n\tThe %s hash is: "%s" [%d bytes]\n\n', algorithm, hashStr, nBytes);


% SIZE OF THE DIFFERENT HASHES:
%       SHA1:  20 bytes = 20 hex codes =  40 char hash string
%     SHA256:  32 bytes = 32 hex codes =  64 char hash string
%     SHA384:  48 bytes = 48 hex codes =  96 char hash string
%     SHA512:  64 bytes = 64 hex codes = 128 char hash string
%        MD5:  16 bytes = 16 hex codes =  32 char hash string
```

REFERENCES:
1) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1
2) https://defuse.ca/checksums.htm#checksums

Comment: Thank you!  This was well organized and worked great for helping me create a function to compute hashes.  If anybody is looking for the same, I uploaded the function as [a gitHub repo](https://github.com/benJephunneh/hasher), but all you need is the m-file.

Answer (score 1):

I just used this and it works well.

Works on strings, files, different data types.
For a file I compared against CRC SHA through file explorer and got the same answer.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31272-datahash